# Batch File for Batch Files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some batch files at different location, but I have copied them in a single folder, now how can I create a batch file which will call all these batch files.

Comment: Notepad? Seriously, have you made any effort to do anything at all to figure this out yourself? At least a basic search here first? *Anything*? Do the "some batch files" have to be run in a specific order, or can they just run randomly?

Comment: i did tried searching how to call batch files or execute batch files from batch file, but didn't got any results to try on and also the files individually ran takes too much time, hence couldnt much palyaround with it.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention running them all at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("c:\folder A\*.bat" "c:\folder A\*.cmd") do call "%%a"
```

Answer (score 1):

i see answers here, but no answer should work here, if you have the wanted files in other folders.
The code will help you to get into other folder is:

```
cd "Folder 1"
```

This is will get into other folder, if you want to create a new folder the code is

```
md "My folder"
```

And dont forget the " ! if you want a folder with few words, dont forget to place " ! the computer will think its a new command. like:

```
md / cd My **Folder**
```

and after this, you can open batch files in currnet window using

```
call "MyCode.bat"
```

or open every kind of files with

```
start "Game.exe"
```

Hope i help you!

Answer (score 0):

Example..

call "C:\users\%username%\desktop\name.bat"

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`call 1.bat
call 2.bat
call 3.bat`

to execute the batch files

You can also use a for statement to execute a call statement for each batch file in a folder

Answer (score 0):

`call` will call a batch file. For example if you have a batch file named `anything.bat`,
`call anything.bat` would call `anything.bat`. So your solution would be

```
call 1.bat
call 2.bat
call 3.bat
call 4.bat
```

Just replace 1.bat with your 1st batch file.
And replace 2.bat with your 2nd batch file.
And replace 3.bat with your 3rd batch file.
And replace 4.bat with your 4th batch file.

Answer (score 0):

well If ALL the batch files are in one folder, then you can do this:

```
call *.bat
```

That will call all of the batch files that are located in the folder.

And if you DON'T want to start them in one file(all batch files started in one), then do this:

```
start *.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

This will call the files `1.bat` and `2.cmd` in the folder `call_me`.
You can have the files in diffrent locations and still work, just replace the `call_me` with the name of the desired folder, such as `Desktop`.

```
Call "%USERPROFILE%\call_me\1.bat" 
Call "%USERPROFILE%\call_me\2.cmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute each batchfile at the same time, you can use this:

```
for %%A in (folder\*.bat) do (
  start %%A
)
```

Just replace folder with the batch-folder.